# Is there a better way to remove a column from a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on an image clustering problem that involves deleting columns. The only way I can think of is using tf.concat to concatenate two slices of the original tensor, and some whitespace. I have to do this many times and I'm worried that it may be slow. Is there a better way to do this?

```
new_tensor = tf.concat(1,
     [tf.slice(data, [0, 0, 0], [to_remove - 1, image_size, 1]),
      tf.slice(data, [to_remove, 0, 0],
                     [image_size - to_remove - 1, image_size, 1]),
      tf.zeros([image_size, 1], tf.float32)])
```

Comment: Could you paste your code so that other people can understand your intention?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.gather`, which better corresponds to what you are trying to do, but honestly I'm not sure if it will be any faster:

```
ind = tf.concat(0, [tf.range(0, to_remove), tf.range(to_remove + 1, data.get_shape()[0])])
removed = tf.gather(ind, data)
zero_filled = tf.concat(0, [removed, tf.zeros([image_size, 1], tf.float32)])
```

Btw, in `slice` you can use `-1` to denote "till the end of this dimension".